# Linux Ubuntu Mysql issue

Tags: mysql

I am not sure if something is wrong with my mysql (runing on dedi server). I might have missconfiguared something, or using a wrong port to connect to, or if it's getting blocked. I'm quite new with linux ubuntu, so i'd be very thankful if you could help me out. Also, sorry for bad English.

`sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql` gives me no output which is strange, shouldn't it say the port mysql is on?

`service mysql status`

```
mysql start/running, process 22992
```

With putty, i can also log in to mysql with `mysql -u root -p` and it works fine. What port is being used when loging in on localhost via ssh?

I can also log in to the phpmyadmin from my computer which is on 7777 port, is that the same port mysql localhost uses?

I use a java plugin on a Game Server which should connect to the mysql but fails to.
Config file:

```
host: 127.0.0.1
port: tried 3306 and 7777
user: root
pass: *****
```

"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server."

/etc/mysql/my.cnf:

```
[client]
port<--><------->= 3306

[mysqld]
user = mysql
port = 3306
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

`sudo netstat -tap | grep 3306` no output

phpmy admin thru webbrowser `sudo netstat -tap | grep 7777`

```
tcp        0      0 *:7777                  *:*                     LISTEN      1566/apache2
```

Comment: That is indeed unusual. You seem to have MySQL running on the default port (as per your `my.cnf` and `mysql -u root -p`) but it does not turn up in `netstat`. (Your `my.cnf` looks strange though - with the dashes and brackets. Did you put them there?) Assuming 22992 is still the correct pid, what does `sudo netstat -tap | grep 22992` give you?

Comment: Here is a full my.cnf (http://pastebin.com/QmkyN9YL)
Output is empty

Comment: and those weird dashes appeared when i opend the file while on "mc"

Comment: Your MySQL server seems to be running OK, but it is configured to be accessed only from localhost. That explains why the game server is not able to connect to it. Can you login on the MySQL server once again and do a `ps -ef|grep mysql`, so we can see what the actual command is? If that doesn't turn up anything, do `ps -ef|grep 22992` if that is still the process ID that you get from `service mysql status`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FfhJPbLb

Comment: the thing is that the game server is on the same machine, so it should be defined as localhost as well

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL server is not configured for access over the network, which is the default, for security reasons. Please see the help in the configuration file to configure the service for access through the network.

The reason the game server does not see the MySQL server is that the game server tries to access the database over the network; it does not try `localhost`. If you did `mysql -h [ip-address] -u root -p` you would not get a connection either. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-networking).

Comment: The game server is on the same machine, and i tried putting both 127.0.0.1 and lochalhost as "host". Does it not allow some sort of connections in the localhost?

Comment: If i put my machine's ip i can still connect to the mysql with that command. Edit: Never mind i cant!

Comment: how would I change that rule to allow connections from my machine's ip?

Comment: I think all you need to change is the `bind-address` from `127.0.0.1` to the real IP address.

Comment: do i need to use "service mysql restart" after that?

Comment: Just what I was going to say. Yes.

Comment: hmm, still getting the same error. How would I temporary remove that rule to check if it fixes it, and how would I put it back?

Comment: Google "configure mysql for network access" for details on how to do this.